# how to get the the multiple selected check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to get the id of the multiple selected check boxes

**HTML**:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="a" id="1">1
<input type="checkbox" class="a" id="2">2
<input type="checkbox" class="a" id="3">3
<input type="checkbox" class="a" id="4">4
<input type="checkbox" class="a" id="5">5

<input type="button" value="Button" id="button">
```

**JS:**

```
$("#button").live('click',function(){
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
    alert(a);
    alert(a.checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHHLX/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why everyone is posting code to check the boxes?

> I want to **get the id** of the multiple **selected check boxes**

To do that, use this code:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var selected = $(".a:checked").map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();
    alert(selected.join(","));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/uHHLX/3/)

You should also not use `live()`. `delegate()` or `on()` are the better solutions, but they are only required should the `#button` element be added to the page after page load.

Comment: I read the question and then the first answer, and when I saw `live` in it I guess I was blanked by it... `:)`

Answer (score 4):

**To get the `id`s of the checked:**

```
$('.a').filter(function(){
    return this.checked // Takes only checked checkboxes.
}).map(function(){
    return this.id // Makes an array which its elements are the ids.
}).get(); // Returns the array.
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jGFUN/2/)

**Note that id that begins with a number isn't valid according to the w3c spec!**

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

**To check the `checkboxes:`**

Don't use `live` unless your jQuery version is < 1.4.4

```
$("#containerId").on('click','#button', function(){
  $('.a').prop('checked', true);
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jGFUN/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("body").on("click", "#button", function(){
    var ids = $(':checkbox.a')
        .filter(':checked')
        .map(function() {
            return this.id;
        });
    console.log(ids); // an array of ids
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RGbrm/1/)**

**Or**

```
$("body").on("click", "#button", function(){
    var ids = $(':checkbox:checked.a')
        .map(function() {
            return this.id;
        }).toArray();
    console.log(ids); // an array of ids
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NXmCj/3/)**

**Or**

```
$("body").on("click", "#button", function(){
    var ids = $(':checkbox.a')
        .map(function() {
            if( this.checked )
                return this.id;
        }).toArray();
    console.log(ids); // an array of ids
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NXmCj/2/)**

Comment: How does the last thing over here returns the id?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
$("#button").live('click',function(){
    $("input:checkbox").each(function()
    {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert( $(this).attr('id') )
        }
    });
});
```

I hope it help you

Comment: please, `$(this).is(':checked')` => `this.checked`.